# PHP MYSQL Join Query. SELECT WHERE AND IN OR Logic Error

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, where-clause

Hey all. I think I have a logic error in my qry. The output is correct but in triplets. I’ve been staring at this for a long time and not seeing it. Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks!!

Also wanted to add this info as well.

- $userid = 1
- $UserIDAList = (1,1,6)
- $UserIDBList = (2,3,1)

PHP-Code:

```
$result  = mysql_query("SELECT TBL_ContactsList.ContactID, TBL_ContactName.FirstName FROM TBL_ContactsList, TBL_ContactName WHERE ((TBL_ContactName.NameID != $userid) AND (TBL_ContactsList.ContactID != $userid)) AND ((TBL_ContactName.NameID IN ($UserIDAList) OR TBL_ContactName.NameID IN $UserIDBList)))");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Only the SQL-Query (readability):

```
SELECT TBL_ContactsList.ContactID, TBL_ContactName.FirstName 
FROM TBL_ContactsList, TBL_ContactName 
WHERE ((TBL_ContactName.NameID != $userid) AND (TBL_ContactsList.ContactID != $userid)) 
AND ((TBL_ContactName.NameID IN ($UserIDAList) OR TBL_ContactName.NameID IN $UserIDBList)))
```

Output:

```
ID: 2 Name: Joe
ID: 3 Name: Joe
ID: 4 Name: Joe
ID: 2 Name: Jimbo
ID: 3 Name: Jimbo
ID: 4 Name: Jimbo
ID: 2 Name: Mike
ID: 3 Name: Mike
```

EDIT: Here is what I ended up using. (can't figure out indent on here.)

But now I am missing an entry from the db.

`$result = mysql_query("

    SELECT cl.ContactID, cn.FirstName

    FROM TBL_ContactName AS cn

    INNER JOIN TBL_ContactsList AS cl

        ON cl.ContactID = cn.NameID

    WHERE

        cn.NameID != $userid

    AND (

        cn.NameID IN ($UserIDBList) OR cn.NameID IN ($UserIDAList)

    )

");`

The output looks like this.
ID: 2 Name: Joe
ID: 3 Name: Jimbo

But when I put LEFT JOIN I get this. Close but still missing ID.
ID: 2 Name: Joe
ID: 3 Name: Jimbo
ID: Name: Mike

Any ideas?? THanks!

Comment: Instead of `FROM TBL_ContactsList, TBL_ContactName` you should try a LEFT or a RIGHT join depending on your table struct

Comment: hey johnp, you're right. from all the comments, it was the JOIN ON that I was missing. thanks!

Comment: Thanks all! I went with @Arda and @dnl answers. But now I am missing a entry on the query. After some experimenting, using LEFT JOIN almost got it, except it is missing the ID. I edited the question about with the code so far and the output.

Comment: Indent isn't hard. Press your space bar.

Comment: ok, i figured out my problem. In the end, i had to make two qrys, one for UserIDA and UserIDB. But all the help in the JOINs make it possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your SQL structure correctly, changing SQL like this should probably fix it. At least it's a proper usage.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT cl.ContactID, cn.FirstName FROM TBL_ContactsList cl INNER JOIN TBL_ContactName cn ON cn.NameID=cl.ContactID WHERE cn.NameID != $userid AND (CN.NameID IN ($UserIDAList) OR CL.NameID IN ($UserIDBList))");
```

Comment: Thanks Arda! This did it! But its now not returning one entry from the db. im gonna look into that. but this did it!

Answer (score 2):

You should indent and shortcut your SQL for better readability

```
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT cl.ContactID, cl.FirstName
  FROM TBL_ContactsList cl
  JOIN TBL_ContactName cn
  WHERE (
    cn.NameID != $userid AND
    cl.ContactID != $userid
  ) AND (
    cn.NameID IN ($UserIDAList) OR 
    cn.NameID IN ($UserIDBList)
  )
");
```

Comment: Hey sod, i went with the other answers that had the ON to make the qry alittle more readable. thanks!

Comment: IMHO, aliasing table names with single- or double-letter names does NOT improve readability. It's like having single- or double-letter variable names all around the programming code - every time you look at the code, you have to look at some other part of code just to find out what all those "fl", "fr", "hl" etc actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

please give feedback, if this works out for you:

```
SELECT cl.ContactID, cn.FirstName 
  FROM TBL_ContactName AS cn 
  JOIN TBL_ContactsList as cl
    ON cn.NameID = cn.ContactID
  WHERE cn.NameID != $userid
    AND (cn.NameID IN ($UserIDAList) OR cn.NameID  IN ($UserIDBList));
```

Comment: This almost did it dnl, thanks! but i kept getting an error and so i went with Arda answer with "=" instead of "==" for the ON. thank you got getting me on the right track!